# The F# equivalent of C#'s 'out'

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am rewriting a C# library to F# and I need to translate the following code

```
bool success;
instance.GetValue(0x10, out success);
```

what is the equivalent of the `out` keyword in F#?

Comment: For new visitors, since F# 4.5 it supports managed pointers, you can use `inref` (read-only ref), `outref` (write only ref), `byref` (read/write ref). It is valid on parameters and as return type, but there are [certain restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs) to prevent them to escape scope willy nilly. Your code would become `GetValue(0x10, success outref)`, where `success` is mutable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Neither wasatz's answer nor Max Malook's is complete.  There are three ways of calling methods with `out` parameters.  The second and third ways also work with `ref` parameters.

For the examples, assume the following type:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices //for OutAttribute
type SomeType() =
    member this.GetValue (key, [<Out>] success : bool byref) =
        if key = 10 then
            success <- true
            "Ten"
        else
            success <- false
            null
```

Assume also that we have an instance of that type:

```
let o = SomeType()
```

### Option 1

You can let the F# compiler handle the out parameter by tupling it with the return value:

```
let result1, success1 = o.GetValue 10
let result2, success2 = o.GetValue 11
```

Running the above lines in F# interactive yields

```
val success1 : bool = true
val result1 : string = "Ten"
val success2 : bool = false
val result2 : string = null
```

### Option 2

You can use a mutable value, passing its address with the `&` operator:

```
let mutable success3 = false
let result3 = o.GetValue (10, &success3)
let mutable success4 = false
let result4 = o.GetValue (11, &success4)
```

In F# interactive, the result is

```
val mutable success3 : bool = true
val result3 : string = "Ten"
val mutable success4 : bool = false
val result4 : string = null
```

This option is best when you are delegating to another method, since you can pass the calling method's out parameter directly to the called method.  For example, if you are implementing a wrapper around `IDictionary<_,_>`, you can code the `TryGetValue` method as

```
//...
interface IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> with
    member this.TryGetValue (key, value) = inner.TryGetValue (key, &value)
    //...
```

### Option 3

You can use a reference cell:

```
let success5 = ref false
let result5 = o.GetValue (10, success5)
let success6 = ref false
let result6 = o.GetValue (11, success6)
```

The output:

```
val success5 : bool ref = {contents = true;}
val result5 : string = "Ten"
val success6 : bool ref = {contents = false;}
val result6 : string = null
```

### Warning!

Be careful not to use the `ref` keyword as you would in C# for an in/out parameter.  For example, the following does not yield the desired result:

```
let success7 = false
let result7 = o.GetValue (10, ref success7)
```

The output:

```
val success7 : bool = false
val result7 : string = "Ten"
```

Why does `success7` hold the value `false`?  Because `success7` is an immutable variable.

In C#, `ref` calls attention to the fact that you are passing a reference to a variable as the argument for a `ref` parameter.  It simply serves as insurance that the programmer of the caller is aware that the variable may be modified by the called method.  In F# however, `ref` creates a new reference cell holding *a copy of* the value of the following expression.

In this case, we are making a reference cell that holds the value copied from the `success7` variable, but not assigning that new reference cell to any variable.  We then pass that reference cell to the GetValue method, which modifies the content of the reference cell.  Because the calling method has no variable pointing to the modified cell, it has no way of reading the new value of the reference cell.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably return an option or a tuple instead. Because F# has pattern matching you really don't need out parameters since there are better ways to return more than one value from a function.

So, something like this would be more idiomatic

```
let (value, success) = instance.GetValue(0x10)
```

where instance.GetValue is a

```
unit -> ('a, bool)
```

Or you could return an option and do something like

```
match instance.GetValue(0x10) with
| Some value -> doStuff value
| None -> failwith "Oops!"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My post does not mention the important fact that I cannot change `GetValue` as it is a part of a third party library. It could make sense to wrap the `out` behavior in something along the lines of your suggestion.

Comment: Actually, the F# compiler will convert a method with out parameters into a method that returns a tuple.  That is one of three ways to call a method with out parameters.  Max Malook's answer covers another of the three.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a [reference cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx).

```
let success = ref false
instance.GetValue(0x10, success)

// access the value
!success
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use a reference cell; it is one of three possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's also worth mentioning here that the value of the out parameter doesn't have to be initialized.

It is possible to do the following:

```
let mutable success3 = Unchecked.defaultof<bool>
let result3 = o.GetValue (10, &success3)
```

This might be usefull in scenarios where you are calling a .NET library function with arrays as output parameters, i.e:

```
let mutable currFeatures = Unchecked.defaultof<PointF[]>
let mutable status = Unchecked.defaultof<byte[]>
let mutable trackError = Unchecked.defaultof<float32[]>

CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
      previousFrame, 
      nextFrame, 
      previousPoints, 
      Size(15,15), 
      2, 
      MCvTermCriteria(10, 0.03), 
      //Out params 
      &currFeatures, 
      &status, 
      &trackError,
      //---------
      LKFlowFlag.UserInitialFlow)
```