# Having trouble converting external Windows Crypto API calls from C# to F#

Tags: winapi, f#, cryptoapi

I've got some working C# code to work with some Windows API calls (based on [my Get-CertificatePath.ps1 PowerShell script](https://github.com/brianary/scripts/blob/master/Get-CertificatePath.ps1#L64)), but the F# version fails. I'm sure I'm missing something, most likely an attribute, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Is there a way to get the F# version working?

### keyname.csx

Run using `csi.exe` from the `microsoft-build-tools` Chocolatey package.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

public static class CryptoApi
{
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll")]
    internal static extern SafeNCryptKeyHandle CertDuplicateCertificateContext(IntPtr certContext); // CERT_CONTEXT *
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle pCert,
                                          uint dwFlags,
                                          IntPtr pvReserved, // void *
                                          [Out] out SafeNCryptKeyHandle phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
                                          [Out] out int dwKeySpec,
                                          [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey);
    [SecurityCritical]
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    public static string GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        SafeNCryptKeyHandle privateKey = null;
        int keySpec = 0;
        bool freeKey = true;
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(CertDuplicateCertificateContext(certificate.Handle),
                                          0x00040000, // AcquireOnlyNCryptKeys
                                          IntPtr.Zero, out privateKey, out keySpec, out freeKey);
        return CngKey.Open(privateKey, CngKeyHandleOpenOptions.None).UniqueName;
    }
}

X509Certificate2 getMyCert(string subject)
{
    using(var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, false);
        Console.WriteLine("found {0} certs", certs.Count);
        store.Close();
        return certs[0];
    }
}

var cert = getMyCert("localhost");
Console.WriteLine("private key? {0}", cert.HasPrivateKey);
Console.WriteLine("key name: {0}", CryptoApi.GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName(cert));
```

The output is:

```
found 1 certs
private key? True
key name: 32fd60███████████████████████████████████-████-████-████-████████████
```

### keyname.fsx

Run using `dotnet fsi` (version 3.1.100; Chocolatey package `dotnetcore` as of this posting).

```ml
#load ".paket/load/netstandard2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.fsx"
#load ".paket/load/netstandard2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.fsx"

open System
open System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
open System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Security
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
open System.Security.Permissions
open Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles

type CryptoApi () =
    [<DllImport("crypt32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    static extern SafeNCryptKeyHandle  internal CertDuplicateCertificateContext(IntPtr certContext) // CERT_CONTEXT *
    [<DllImport("crypt32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)>]
    static extern [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool internal
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle  pCert,
                                          uint32 dwFlags,
                                          IntPtr pvReserved, // void *
                                          SafeNCryptKeyHandle& phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
                                          int& dwKeySpec,
                                          [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool& pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)
    [<SecurityCritical>]
    [<SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)>]
    static member GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName (certificate : X509Certificate2) =
        let mutable privateKey : SafeNCryptKeyHandle = null
        let mutable keySpec = 0
        let mutable freeKey = true
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(CertDuplicateCertificateContext(certificate.Handle),
                                          0x00040000u, // AcquireOnlyNCryptKeys
                                          IntPtr.Zero, &privateKey, &keySpec, &freeKey) |> ignore
        CngKey.Open(privateKey, CngKeyHandleOpenOptions.None).UniqueName

let getMyCert subject =
    use store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
    let certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, false)
    printfn "found %d certs" certs.Count
    store.Close()
    certs.[0]

let cert = getMyCert "localhost"
printfn "private key? %b" cert.HasPrivateKey
CryptoApi.GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName(cert) |> printfn "%s"
```

The output is:

```
found 1 certs
private key? true
System.ArgumentNullException: SafeHandle cannot be null. (Parameter 'pHandle')
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.AddToCleanupList(CleanupWorkListElement& pCleanupWorkList, SafeHandle handle)
   at FSI_0003.CryptoApi.CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle pCert, UInt32 dwFlags, IntPtr pvReserved, SafeNCryptKeyHandle& phCryptProvOrNCryptKey, Int32& dwKeySpec, Boolean& pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)
   at FSI_0003.CryptoApi.GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

### paket.dependencies

This is required for the .fsx file above to work, then run `paket install`.

```
generate_load_scripts: true
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

storage: none
framework: netcore3.0, netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1
nuget System.Security.Cryptography.Cng
nuget System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
```

**Edit:** Initializing `let mutable privateKey = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle ()` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Does `&privateKey`/`&keySpec`/`&freeKey` match the type `SafeNCryptKeyHandle&`/`int&`/`bool&` correctly? Please refer to the type correspondence on the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs#interop-with-c

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Yes, at least they match each other (otherwise the F# wouldn't compile), but whether declaration maps accurately to the WinAPI C++ declaration is something I'd like to confirm. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32.cryptacquirecertificateprivatekey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a parameter being passed a null that cannot be a null. The one that jumps out at me is this.

```
let mutable privateKey : SafeNCryptKeyHandle = null
```

Should this instead be a new object?

Comment: That null value works fine in the C# version, though.

Comment: I guess I should have at least tried this, even though it doesn't seem like it makes sense. This was the answer.

Comment: F# is a little more strict about nulls on average.

Comment: I guess I thought the behavior for populating the value was implemented within crypt32.dll, but apparently F# must marshall nulls a bit differently before it gets that far.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to declare the reference type of the function parameter corresponding to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs#interop-with-c).

Here is also a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703716/10611792) from the answer of @phoog.

Using `byref` in F#/`ref` in C# requires initialization, try to use

```
let mutable privateKey : SafeNCryptKeyHandle = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle()
```

UPDATE:

The whole sample:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
open System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Security
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
open System.Security.Permissions
open Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles

type CryptoApi () =
    [<DllImport("crypt32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    static extern SafeNCryptKeyHandle  internal CertDuplicateCertificateContext(IntPtr certContext) // CERT_CONTEXT *
    [<DllImport("crypt32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)>]
    static extern [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool internal
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle  pCert,
                                          uint32 dwFlags,
                                          IntPtr pvReserved, // void *
                                          SafeNCryptKeyHandle& phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
                                          int& dwKeySpec,
                                          [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool& pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)
    [<SecurityCritical>]
    [<SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)>]
    static member GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName (certificate : X509Certificate2) =
        let mutable privateKey : SafeNCryptKeyHandle = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle()
        let mutable keySpec = 0
        let mutable freeKey = true
        CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(CertDuplicateCertificateContext(certificate.Handle),
                                          0x00040000u, // AcquireOnlyNCryptKeys
                                          IntPtr.Zero, &privateKey, &keySpec, &freeKey) |> ignore
        CngKey.Open(privateKey, CngKeyHandleOpenOptions.None).UniqueName

let getMyCert subject =
    use store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
    let certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, false)
    printfn "found %d certs" certs.Count
    store.Close()
    certs.[0]

let cert = getMyCert "localhost"
printfn "private key? %b" cert.HasPrivateKey
CryptoApi.GetCngUniqueKeyContainerName(cert) |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: The params appear to be marked both `In` and `Out` refs (though the C# version doesn't seem to need to pass any valid values in). http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32.cryptacquirecertificateprivatekey However, WinAPI functions are C++ interop (P/Invoke), not C# interop, so I'm not sure this syntax will work.

Comment: When I try the param syntax `outref<SafeNCryptKeyHandle> phCryptProvOrNCryptKey` or `SafeNCryptKeyHandle outref phCryptProvOrNCryptKey`, it doesn't compile. It doesn't seem like this syntax is compatible with `extern` declarations.

Comment: Your issue in F# is the same as if you replace `out` with `ref` in C#.

Comment: Interesting, let me try replacing `&` with `[<Out>]`, then. It's where I started, but I may have changed other things.

Comment: Using `ref` requires initialization, while `out` does not. try to use `let mutable privateKey : SafeNCryptKeyHandle = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle()`.

Comment: Removing the `&` from both the declaration and the call, then adding `[<Out>]` to the declaration params didn't change the null exception. Adding `outref` to either the `extern` declaration or the function call doesn't compile.

Comment: `let mutable privateKey = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle()` results in an `AccessViolationException` "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.", which might be progress, but I'm even less sure about how I'd diagnose that.

Comment: Switching back to the `&` syntax, but keeping the initialized `privateKey` worked! That's really weird. I'm not sure why C# and F# would operate this differently.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I mean, if you use `&` (this represents `byref` type), you need to `new safencryptkeyhandle()`, to restore your original code, just modify `let mutable privatekey: safencryptkeyhandle = new safencryptkeyhandle()`

Answer (score 1):

Even though OP has a work-around I was wondering why the F# code crashed. After some digging around using `dnspy` I found that the interop functions differed subtly.

First there is a bug in the F# interop code in that it should use `winapi` calling conventon not `cdecl`. However, fixing that bug didn't fix the issue.

What seems to make a difference is that the C# interop functions out parameters are tagged as `out`.

```
.method assembly hidebysig static pinvokeimpl("crypt32.dll" lasterr winapi) 
  bool marshal(bool) CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey (
    class [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng]Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle pCert,
    uint32 dwFlags,
    native int pvReserved,
    [out] class [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng]Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle& phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
    [out] int32& dwKeySpec,
    [out] bool& marshal(bool) pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey
  ) cil managed preservesig
```

In F# they are `ref`:

```
.method assembly static pinvokeimpl("crypt32.dll" lasterr cdecl) 
  bool CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey (
    class [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng]Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle pCert,
    uint32 dwFlags,
    native int pvReserved,
    class [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng]Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeNCryptKeyHandle& phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
    int32& dwKeySpec,
    bool& pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey
  ) cil managed preservesig
```

If I change the F# code to call the C# interop functions it works for me. This implies to me that the jitter adds verification to make sure that we don't pass null `SafeHandle` if the it's a `ref` parameter but not if it's `out`.

I tried to add `[Out]` attribute to the F# interop functions but they seem discarded (also note F# discarded `[<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>]`). Perhaps there's some way to do it but the [F# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/external-functions) is rather succinct in this regard.

Using `outref<_>`:s didn't compile.

I also checked the F# parser code to see if I could see some way to add the out attribute but alas no I couldn't see a way to do it: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/pars.fsy#L2558

I did however understand why `outref<_>` doesn't work as the `cType` parser only supports very limited types.

I think creating an F# issue should be a reasonable next step. Hopefully it's just a documentation issue.

Comment: Thanks for digging so deep for this! I'm not sure I'd be able to articulate or defend a bug report at a level this low, if this is something you'd like to report.