# F# - Use C# methods with out parameter (within arrays and void return)

Tags: f#, out, c#-to-f#

I've read [the-f-equivalent-of-cs-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691162/the-f-equivalent-of-cs-out) but still I can't make it work for my case (the simplest solution/syntax).

I have this method in a C# project:

```cs
//<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
//<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>

public static void ABC(out byte[] a, out byte[] b, byte[] c)
{
    var aaa = new byte[10];
    var bbb = new byte[10];            
    a = aaa;
    b = bbb;
}
```

Now, I want to use it in a F# project:
I'm using *FSharp.Core 4.7.2*

```ml
(* <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks> *)

let a,b = ABC(c)
```

I'm imitating the syntax of `TryParse` and this compiles without errors:

```ml
let success, number = System.Int32.TryParse("0")
```

The compiler on my `ABC(c)` call complains about the fact the signature asks for 3 parameters, not 1.
Compared to the `TryParse` I see 2 differences:

- It does not return `void`
- It uses Array objects

The compiler accepts this syntax:

```ml
let a = Array.empty<byte>
let b = Array.empty<byte>
ABC(ref a, ref b, c)
```

but:

1. I think it is not correct to use `ref` here, not in this way (because `a` and `b` are not mutable)
2. I'd like to use the clean syntax similar to `TryParse` and I WANT to know why it does not work here

I can change the C# project code, but replacing all the `out` parameters in that proejct will be a second step and maybe a new qeustion if I have difficulties or doubt.

**[Update: parameter position]**

I played a little with this and seems like I found when the "simple" syntax (without passing ref parameters) is broken.

```cs
public static void TryParseArray(string input, out int[] result) {
    result = new int[0];
}

public static void TryParseArray_2(out int[] result, string input) {
    result = new int[0];
}
```

```ml
let arr = csharp.TryParseArray("a")            // OK
let arr = csharp.TryParseArray_2("a")          // ERROR
```

It seems like the out parameter must be at the end (= not followed by normal parameters) in the C# methods, to make possible for F# to use them as returned tuple.

Comment: You can used the `ref` cell syntax, but not like that, instead define the `a` and `b` variables as a `ref Array.empty<byte>` and then pass it in as an argument (without the ref keyword). You could also just make them `mutable` and pass in the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly noticed that the "simplified" F# syntax for turning out parameters into returned tuples only works in very limited situations - only when you have one parameter and it is the last one. In other words, this feature helps with some common patterns, but it does not fully replace out parameters.

If you want to use `out` parameter in F#, you can either pass a reference to a local mutable variable using the `&var` syntax, or you can specify a reference cell of type `int ref` as an argument. The following shows the two options using the standard `TryParse` method:

```
// Using a local mutable variable
let mutable n = 0
Int32.TryParse("42", &n)
printfn "Got: %d" n

// Using a reference cell initialized to 0 
let n = ref 0
Int32.TryParse("42", n)
printfn "Got: %d" n.Value
```